# What can we say about the eigenvalues and diagonalization of this $2N\times2N$ matrix $A$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

There is a $2N\times2N$ matrix $A$, where $N$ is a positive integer, which is of the form:

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B & C\\
-C^{*} & -B^{*}
\end{array}\right),$

where $B$ is a hermitian matrix, and $C$ is a symmetric matrix.

> What can we say about the eigenvalues of $A$ and it's diagonalization?

For example, if $N=1$:

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
b & c\\
-c^{*} & -b^{*}
\end{array}\right),$

where $b$ must be a real number, and $c$ has no restriction .

The eigenvalues are the same if and only if $\mid c\mid=\mid b\mid$,
and the eigenvalues are equal to $0$. But the matrix $A$ is not
diagonalizable under this condition:

$A=b\left(\begin{array}{cc}
1 & e^{i\theta}\\
-e^{-i\theta} & -1
\end{array}\right)=b\left(\begin{array}{cc}
-e^{i\theta} & -e^{i\theta}\\
1 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{cc}
0 & 1\\
-e^{-i\theta} & -1
\end{array}\right).$

Is this an accident only for $N=1$ case? Is there some relation like
this for general cases $N>1$?

Comment: I find the eigenvalues of this type of matrix are always in pairs $\pm\lambda$, but don't know how to prove it, then I ask this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1722961/how-to-prove-the-eigenvalues-of-this-matrix-a-come-in-pairs-pm-lambda)

Comment: The previous property is proved in the question. And later on, I find the eigenvalues of this type of matrix are also in pairs of $\lambda$ and $\lambda^{*}$, which is able to be proved in the similar way.