# How to prove the eigenvalues of this matrix $A$ come in pairs $\pm\lambda$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This is a branched question of my previous question [What's the condition for a matrix $A$ ($2N\times 2N$ dimension) to have eigenvalues in pairs $\pm\lambda$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1718821/whats-the-condition-for-a-matrix-a-2n-times-2n-dimension-to-have-eigenval).

Let's look at this $2N\times2N$ matrix $A$:

$A=\left(\begin{array}{cc}
B & C\\
-C^{*} & -B^{*}
\end{array}\right)$,

where $B$ is a hermitian matrix, $C$ is a complex symmetric matrix, and $M^\ast$ denotes the complex conjugate (but **not** the conjugate transpose) of a matrix $M$.

If $A$ is a $2\times2$ matrix, the eigenvalues are obviously in
pairs, and I also proved the $4\times4$ case by showing the determinant
of $A-\lambda I$ only depends on $\lambda^{2}$.

Then I use Mathematica to calculate the eigenvalues of this
matrix with randomly generated matrices $B$ and $C$ for higher dimension
cases, the eigenvalues also come in pairs. So I guess this matrix
always has eigenvalues in pairs, but I don't know how to prove it
analytically.

Comment: Is $B^*$ the conjugate transpose of $B$, i.e. $B^*=\overline{B}^T$?

Comment: $B^{*}$ is the complex conjugate of $B$, and I use $B^{\dagger}$
as the conjugate transpose of $B$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suppose you are given an eigenvector relative to $\lambda$ and write it as $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}v\\ w\end{smallmatrix}\right]$:
$$
\lambda\begin{bmatrix}
v \\ w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B & C \\
-C^* & -B^*
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
v \\ w
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
Bv+Cw \\ -C^*v-B^*w
\end{bmatrix}
$$
This means
$$
\begin{cases}
Bv+Cw=\lambda v\\[4px]
-C^*v-B^*w=\lambda w
\end{cases}
$$
Since $C$ is symmetric and $B$ is hermitian, we have
$$
A^T=
\begin{bmatrix}
B^T & -(C^*)^T \\
C^T & -(B^*)^T
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B^* & -C^* \\
C & -B
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and we have
$$
A^T\begin{bmatrix}
w \\ -v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B^* & -C^* \\
C & -B
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
w \\ -v
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
B^*w+C^*v \\
Cw+Bv
\end{bmatrix}
=
\begin{bmatrix}
-\lambda w\\
\lambda v
\end{bmatrix}=
-\lambda\begin{bmatrix}w\\-v\end{bmatrix}
$$
Therefore $-\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A^T$. It is well known that $A$ and $A^T$ have the same eigenvalues.

*Important note.* In the above, as explained in the comments to the question, $B^*$ denotes the matrix obtained by conjugating each entry in $B$, so the condition for $B$ being hermitian is $B^T=B^*$. Similarly, $(C^*)^T=(C^T)^*=C^*$ since $C$ is symmetric.

Comment: Oh, my bad. The OP defines $B^\ast$ as $\bar{B}$. Sorry for my previous comment.